# How do I define synthetic attributes for an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I have an ActiveRecord model whose fields *mostly* come from the database.  There are additional attributes, which come from a nested serialised blob of stuff.  This has been done so that I can use these attributes from forms without having to jump through hoops (or so I thought in the beginning, anyway) while allowing forwards and backwards compatibility without having to write complicated migrations.

Basically I am doing this:

```
class Licence < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :load_worker_count
  strip_attributes!

  validates_numericality_of :load_worker_count,
    :greater_than => 2, :allow_nil => true, :allow_blank => true

  before_save :serialise_fields_into_properties

  def serialise_fields_into_properties
    ...
  end

  def after_initialize
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

The problem I noticed was that I can't get empty values in `:load_worker_count` to be accepted by the validator, because:

- If I omit `:allow_blank`, it fails validation complaining about it being blank
- If I put in `:allow_blank`, it converts the blank to 0, which when fails on the `:greater_than => 2`

In tracking down why these blank values are getting to the validation stage in the first place, I discovered the root of the problem: **`strip_attributes!` only affects actual attributes, as returned by the `attributes` method.**  So the values which should be nil at time of validation are not.  So it feels like the root cause is that the synthetic attributes I added in aren't seen when setting which attributes to strip, so therefore I ask:

Is there a proper way of creating synthetic attributes which are recognised as proper attributes by other code which integrates with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking of the `strip_attributes` plugin; looking at the code, it uses the method `attributes`, defined in active_record/base.rb, which uses `@attributes`, which is initialized (in `initialize`) as `@attributes = attributes_from_column_definition`.

Maybe it's possible to hack ActiveRecord::Base somehow, but it would be a hard work: `@attributes` is also used when getting/putting stuff from/to db, so you would have to do a lot of hacking.

There's a much simpler solution:

```
before_validate :serialise_fields_into_properties
...

def serialise_fields_into_properties
  if load_worker_count.respond_to? :strip
    load_worker_count = load_worker_count.blank? ? nil : load_worker_count.strip
  end
  ...
end
```

After all, this is what strip_attributes! does.

Comment: The thought of reimplementing `strip_attributes!` in my own code did occur to me (though it has to be `before_validate` rather than `before_save`, as my problem is occurring at validation.)

Comment: I'll stress it once again: don't try to change the behaviour of how db attributes and non-db attributes are managed, it would be a huge work, and you should test it against *all* existing and future plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just use Rails' serialize macro here?

```
class License < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :special_attributes
end
```

Now you can assign a hash or array or whatever you need to special_attributes and Rails will serialize it a text field in the database.

```
license = License.new
license.special_attributes = { :beer => true, :water => false }
```

This will keep your code clean and you don't have to worry about serializing/deserializing attributes yourself.

Comment: I wasn't keen on doing this, but my only reason is that I wanted to access these as normal fields from the form, i.e. I prefer to do this:

    licence.count = 5

And it's also much easier to validate if you can use `validates_numericality_of` directly.

Using serialize is on my list of things for the future.  At the moment they're being serialised in a text format which I can directly use for other purposes but it's causing a bit of overhead implementing the conversion in both directions.